# php: strip everything except alphanumeric unicode and two characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get a strip a text from all punctuation but since the text is in Spanish I can't use [A-Za-z0-9].
I have found this regex:

```
trim(preg_replace('#[^\p{L}\p{N}]+#u', ' ', $str)
```

which seems to do the job, but I would like to keep two special characters @ and #, how can I achieve that?

Extra question: How can I delete all strings that are just numbers? e.g. 123 would be deleted but not as5623.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add those characters to your negated class to retain them. And be sure to change your pattern delimiters to something other than `#` as well.

```
~[^\p{L}\p{N}@#]+~u
```

To remove all strings that are numbers, you can place word boundaries `\b` around your pattern.

```
\b\d+\b
```

**Note:** A word boundary does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

Comment: Thank you, I get an error about an unknown modifier ] for:  trim(preg_replace('#[^\p{L}\p{N}@#]+#u', ' ', $str));

Do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use posix character classes too.

```
/[^[:alnum:]@#]+/
```

But for the two special character, you just have to add it inside character class.

To delete all the only number containing words following regex would work.

```
/\b[[:digit:]]+\b/
```